# Crouton is overlaying the toolbar on the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

The Crouton should ideally display underneath the toolbar, for context-sensitive updates that don't block content actions.

[image: croutonOverlay]

Comment: This shouldn't have been migrated.

Comment: @ShadowWizard why not?  It's an app question.  Belongs on MSE.  We don't need them on both MSO and MSE.  Migrate and merge is probably the best course of action, but migration and mark as a dup seems to be appropriate as well.

Comment: @psubsee2003 because OP asked exact same question here as well. No point having the exact same bug report twice. (duplicate is for similar cases, by two different users usually)

Comment: Who the hell called that thing a crouton in the first place? This is not salad!

Comment: It's a more contextual replacement for toast notifications!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Crouton library displays over the actionbar/toolbar when called from an Activity's context, without the viewgroup parameter.

Creating a small FrameLayout above your main content and attaching the crouton to this will fix the issue.

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/crouton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Note: choosing `wrap-content` for your layout-height will cause the crouton to be consumed by the layout before it is properly cancelled, causing double notifications or jerky behaviour.

```
Crouton.makeText(
      MainActivity.this,
      croutonText,
      croutonStyle,
      R.id.crouton
 ).show();
```

Alternatively, you can directly attach it to the content view, if you wish to do it programmatically:

```
// Find content view and cast to ViewGroup, to attach crouton
View homeBtn = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Crouton.makeText(
      MainActivity.this,
      croutonText,
      croutonStyle,
      (ViewGroup) homeBtn)
 ).show();
```

Comment: I don't know android, so not sure if it will work, but I like that you've found the issue and suggested a fix! +1

Comment: Thanks! I ran into the same issue last year, so i'm hoping the fix will be of some use to the dev.